# openpyxl 'TypeError: expected <class 'int'>'

Tags: excel, python-3.6, openpyxl

Python 3.6 Newest openpyxl
So, I'm working with an excel using openpyxl. I have a very boring test.xlsx excel, which I can read with the following code:

```
import os
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
print(sheet)
```

However, when I change to a fairly complex excel document 'apqptest.xlsx.'

```
import os
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('apqptest.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
print(sheet)
```

I get the following error (I have created the same sheet1 on the apqptest.xlsx document just fyi):

```
 C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/nkent/Desktop/Programs/Quote Preperation.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
        value = expected_type(value)
    TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/nkent/Desktop/Programs/Quote Preperation.py", line 3, in <module>
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('apqptest.xlsx')
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 274, in load_workbook
        for c in find_charts(archive, rel.target):
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reader.py", line 43, in find_charts
        drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing.from_tree(tree)
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
        obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
        obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
        obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 100, in from_tree
        return cls(**attrib)
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\graphic.py", line 53, in __init__
        self.rot = rot
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 69, in __set__
        value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
      File "C:\Users\nkent\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
        raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
    TypeError: expected <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Your question is already posted elsewhere.<br>
Please refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905957/cant-load-workbook-with-openpyxl-during-handling-of-the-above-exception-anoth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905957/cant-load-workbook-with-openpyxl-during-handling-of-the-above-exception-anoth).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load workbook with openpyxl: during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905957/cant-load-workbook-with-openpyxl-during-handling-of-the-above-exception-anoth)